# How to update sql agent job using parameterized sql

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, odbc

In my project I want to update the sql agent job by execute a SQL Parameterized Stored Procedures Using the ODBC .NET Provider. So far, this is what i have

```
OdbcCommand ExecJob = new OdbcCommand();           
ExecJob.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
ExecJob.CommandText = "msdb.dbo.sp_update_schedule";
ExecJob.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", "a");
ExecJob.Parameters.AddWithValue("@new_name", " b");                    
ExecJob.Connection = MyConnection;
```

When execute this sql it cause this error `Supply either @schedule_id or @name to identify the schedule.` Anyone can help me with this? I really not so familiar with sql.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the ODBC escape syntax, passing positional parameters:

```
OdbcCommand ExecJob = new OdbcCommand();           
ExecJob.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
ExecJob.CommandText = "call msdb.dbo.sp_update_schedule(?,?,?)";
ExecJob.Parameters.AddWithValue("@schedule_id", Dbnull.Value);
ExecJob.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", "a");
ExecJob.Parameters.AddWithValue("@new_name", "b");                    
ExecJob.Connection = MyConnection;
```